# Не добавляет динамически элементы d ListView

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер. Есть AsyncTask, получающий данные с сервера. Во время работы вызываю

```
onProgressUpdate(Item... values);
{
 super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        items.add(values[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, values[0].toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

где `items` - `ArrayList<Item>`, `adapter` - `ArrayAdapter`. При этом элементы не добавляются(Данные приходят правильные). Если провести такие же действия в `onCreate()` то элемент добавится. Что может быть не так?

Comment: под дебаггером что показывает?

Comment: `adapter` точно содержит именно список `items` а не его копию? Как вы записываете `items` в `adapter`?

Comment: @xkor ,`ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` а адаптер `adapter = new mAdapter(this, items);` `mAdapter` - адаптер для моей разметки

Comment: тогда возможно проблема в коде вашего mAdapter

Comment: @xkor , я могу добавить элемент в том же методе `onCreate()`, в других активностях все работает тоже с этим же адаптером

Comment: @kBro ну с приведенным кодом можно только гадать на кофейной гуще что пошло не так...

Comment: @xkor , проблема решилась. Оказалась, что некорректно работал эмулятор

Comment: @kBro, напишите в ответ как вы решили проблему - это может помочь ещё кому то. Как я понял у вас вторая студия и её эмулятор с возможностью видеть **некоторые** изменения в коде не перезапуская проект на эмуляторе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб "возможность видеть некоторые изменения в коде не перезапуская проект" это фича студии и градла, эмулятор тут не сильно важен, скорее версия андройда. А вообще да, Instant Run фича как по мне сыроватая, у меня она на больших проектах и при частой смене веток в git очень глючит, пришлось отключить.

Comment: @xkor, я ещё как анонс этой фичи услышал сразу почти решил, что обновляться на неё не буду - я прямо увидел множество различных способов того как оно не будет работать))) Ну и не зря - как гугл вторую версию зарелизил тут сразу пошли вопросы на тему "ой, ничего не работает после обновы на вторую версию" =) Подожду версии 2.5)